# NextJs 13.4 React Query with dapr javascript sdk. Module not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js13, dapr, app-router

I am working on a NextJs application that use App Router. I ran into some problems when we wanted to use React Query instead of fetching in server components. I have made a file in app/utils/api.ts.

And I have client component which is going to use React Query to fetch data.
When I try to use my getData function with React Query I get multiple error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs', 'dns', 'https2'.
Which I assume has to do with the network javascript functions not being available in the browser. If I was using Page Router I could have used getServerSideProps, but with App Router I dont know if I'm able to use anything like that. Is it possible to get the data on the server side and use the function inside a React Query? Here I provided some example code:

```
import { DaprClient, HttpMethod } from '@dapr/dapr';
import { DataType} from '../models/Data';

const daprHost = '127.0.0.1'; // Dapr Sidecar Host
const daprPort = '3500'; // Dapr Sidecar Port of this Example Server
const client = new DaprClient({ daprHost, daprPort });

export async function getData() {
  const serviceAppId = 'backendApi';
  const serviceMethod = '/api';
  try {
    // GET Request
    const response = await client.invoker.invoke(
      serviceAppId,
      serviceMethod,
      HttpMethod.GET
    );
    return response as AvvikAPI;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

```
async function PageWithMUI() {
 const { data, isLoading } = useQuery('key', getData);
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { DaprClient, HttpMethod } from '@dapr/dapr';
import {
  Avvik,
  AvvikAPI,
  GrunnmurStatus,
  getFakturaKilder,
} from '../models/Avvik';
import DropdownGrid from './components/DropdownGrid';



The fetching method down below works. I wrapped the Component in a Server Side Component, but since we are using MUI and MUI does not support Server Side Rendering. But this won't be ideal in the long run.

const daprHost = '127.0.0.1'; // Dapr Sidecar Host
const daprPort = '3500'; // Dapr Sidecar Port of this Example Server
const client = new DaprClient({ daprHost, daprPort });

export const revalidate = 60; // revalidate every minute

async function getData() {
  const serviceAppId = 'backendApi';
  const serviceMethod = '/api';
  try {
    // GET Request
    const response = await client.invoker.invoke(
      serviceAppId,
      serviceMethod,
      HttpMethod.GET
    );
    return response as DataType;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return undefined;
  }
}

async function Home() {
  const data: DataType | undefined = await getData();

  return (
    <div className='flex min-h-screen flex-col pt-6 pl-[2.38rem] pr-[3rem] lg:pl-[3rem] bg-[var(--background)]'>
      <h1 className='mb-[1.38rem]'>Grunnmuren - Status</h1>
      <PageWithMUI data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for clearance in answers, but I just can't add a comment as a newbie)

Why would you use client-side /fetching when you can do it in a server component? What's the use case? That DaptClient is not intended to be used in the browser, one possible solution would be to use API Routes as a proxy, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: We have to make all pages that uses MUI compoents client-side with 'use client'. Even if I just want to import a standard Accordian from MUI I can't do that in a Server-Side component. This forces me to create child components just to wrap the MUI Accordion and import that to a server side page.